# How to write conditional required in yup

Tags: reactjs, yup

Hi I want to write a conditional schema in yup.

Here is the schema code:

```
  const Schema = yup.object({
currentLocation: yup
  .string()
  .required('Please enter the Current Location.'),
hometown: yup.string().required('Please enter your HomeTown Location.'),
phoneNumber: yup
  .array()
  .of(yup.string())
  .required('Please enter your Phone Number'),
whatsappNumber: yup
  .array()
  .of(yup.string())
  .required('Please enter your Phone Number'),
hasManager: yup.bool(),
managerName: yup.string(),
managerCompanyName: yup.string(),
managerEmail: yup.string(),
managerContact: yup.string(),
});
```

Now I want to managerName , managecompany.... managercontact to be required only if hasManager is true

How do i do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`when`](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedwhenkeys-string--arraystring-builder-object--value-schema-schema-schema), for example:

```
managerName: yup.string().when('hasManager', {
      is: true,
      then: yup.string().required(),
      otherwise: yup.string()
    }),
```

Or:

```
managerName: yup.string().when('hasManager', (hasManager, schema) => {
    return hasManager ? schema.required() : schema;
  }),
```